# Website Login Error

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, e-commerce, login-script

I created a website login system but when I run it it keeps coming up with this error to the particular bit of coding below.

Error:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code Additional information: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'user'."

Code:

```
        public static User LoginUser(string login, string password)
        {
        //Check if user exists
        string query = string.Format("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TeesDB.dbo.user WHERE name = '{0}'",
        login);
        command.CommandText = query;

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            int amountOfUsers = (int) command.ExecuteScalar(); **<<<<<<< HERE!!!**
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Syntax Error with Database Login System](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22735869/syntax-error-with-database-login-system)

Comment: Hi there. I've cast close votes on a couple of your duplicate questions. If you can refrain from posting the same thing many times it is appreciated - it creates work to edit new questions and/or to close them if necessary. If your question has not had enough views or hasn't received an answer, I think commenting on it gives it some "activity" that brings it into recent lists. Also, don't forget to tag with your language - your two dups did not mention 'asp.net' but your answered question did.