# Ad-hoc query string causes syntax error

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net, syntax-error

I've created a website and a syntax error in my login system keeps occurring.

```
                 conn.Open();
                 int amountOfUsers = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();

                 if (amountOfUsers == 1)
                 {
                //User exists, check if the password match
                query = string.Format("SELECT password FROM users WHERE name = '{0}", login);
                command.CommandText = query;
                string dbPassword = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Website Login Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22734342/website-login-error)

Comment: (Can I get some asp.net readers to VtC, this is a reposted question afaict - thanks).

Comment: Please don't use naked strings to execute SQL statements. Use parameterized queries, they are just as easy to write but a lot faster, safer and completely avoid conversion problems. Image if a user entered `' drop table users;--` as the login name, or just `' OR 1=1;--`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Syntax Error with Database Login System](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22735869/syntax-error-with-database-login-system)

Answer (score 2):

You haven't closed the string identifier `{0}` with apostrophe in format string:

```
query = string.Format("SELECT password FROM users WHERE name = '{0}'", login);
```

But I strongly advise you not to use format strings with SQL as it's a nice security hole for SQL injections!

Comment: Not only a security risk. String conversions cause a lot of problems with numeric and date parameters, performance is worse because execution plans aren't reused etc.