# Syntax Error with Database Login System

Tags: asp.net, web-services, syntax-error, login-script

Created a website login system but when I run it it keeps coming up with this error to the particular bit of coding below. Can someone PLEASE help me with this Error message on this particular code:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'user'.

Code:

```
  public static User LoginUser(string login, string password)
    {
        //Check if user exists
        string query = string.Format("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TeesDB.dbo.user WHERE name = '{0}'",
         login);
        command.CommandText = query;

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            int amountOfUsers = (int) command.ExecuteScalar();

            if(amountOfUsers == 1)
            {
                //User exists, check if the password match
                query = string.Format("SELECT password FROM users WHERE name = '{0}", login);
                command.CommandText = query;
                string dbPassword = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();


                if (dbPassword == password)
                {
                    //password match. Login and password data are known to us.
                    //retrieve further user data from the database
                    query = string.Format("SELECT email, user_type FROM users WHERE name =
                      '{0}'", login);
                    command.CommandText = query;

                    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                    User user = null;

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        string email = reader.GetString(0);
                        string type = reader.GetString(1);

                        user = new User(login, password, email, type);
                    }
                    return user;
                }
                else
                {

                    //passwords do not match
                    return null;

                }

            }
            else
            {

                //user exists
                return null;

            }
        }
        finally
        {

            conn.Close();
         }
       }
      }
     }
```

Comment: Your table is probably named 'users' and not 'user'. Also, you should parameterize your SQL commands because you're at a huge risk for SQL injection. [Give Me Parameterized SQL or Give Me Death](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). Also, please look into something like BCrypt to salt and hash your passwords; don't store them in plaintext!

Comment: Okay cheers, so you think if I change user to users, it should work, thank you for your feedback I appreciate it a lot. Im also very new to this so im not sure what you mean by salt an hash my passwords

Comment: Thank you very much, slight spelling error on my part! thanks for noticing it!

Comment: You should throw away all your code above. Learn about SQL-injection and password hashing and then try again. This is an important part of your site and you should get it right. Also you make 3 database calls when one would be enough.

Answer (score 1):

That happens because USER is a reserved keyword. To refer to it in your queries you need to encapsulate the word between square brackets

```
 string query = string.Format("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [user] WHERE name = .....
```

but at this point, why in subsequent queries you use the name `users`? It is just a typo in the first query or in the next?

However, you should also keep in mind that string formatting your queries in that way is very bad.
You are at risk of Sql Injections and, if a single quote appears in your text values, the whole query will resul in an invalid syntax

As an example of a parameterized query to replace your query

```
 string query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [user] WHERE name = @name",
 command.CommandText = query;
 command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name",login);
 int amountOfUsers = (Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());
 if(amountOfUsers > 0)
 {
    .....
 }
```

Then the next problem is the password retrieved from the database and compared with the user input. Having this kind of code means the password is stored in clear text inside the database. A clear security risk. You should store passwords in an encrypted form. When you need to check the user credentials you apply the same crypting algorithm to the user input and checks against the password in the database.

You could do this in a single operation

```
 string cryptPwd = EncryptPassword(password);
 string query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [user] WHERE name = @name and password = @cryptpwd",
 ....
```

Comment: Got it working thanks a lot for your comments, that actually wasnt the error, the guy above got it spot on!